# Issue with generic type bounds

Tags: scala

I have a following trait:

```
trait Recoverable[M[_]] {
    def recoverW[T, U >: T](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, M[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): M[U]
    def fail[T](error: Throwable): M[T]
}
```

Also I have an implicit conversion method in the same package:

```
implicit def tryRecoverable[T](`try`: Try[T]) = new Recoverable[Try] {
    override def recoverW[T, U >: T](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, Try[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Try[U] = `try`.recoverWith[U](f)
    override def fail[T](error: Throwable): Try[T] = Failure(error)
  }
```

This code doesn't compile complaining with

```
type arguments [U] do not conform to method recoverWith's type parameter bounds [U >: T]
    override def recoverW[T, U >: T](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, Try[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Try[U] = `try`.recoverWith[U](f)
                                                                                                                                            ^
```

Why this code doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `T` inside `recoverW` and `T` inside `tryRecoverable` - are different T's (`[T, ...]` defines new method-scoped `T`), you may:

```
trait Recoverable[M[_]] {
    type TT
    def recoverW[U >: TT](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, M[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): M[U]
    def fail(error: Throwable): M[TT]
}

implicit def tryRecoverable[T](`try`: Try[T]) = new Recoverable[Try] {
    type TT = T
    override def recoverW[U >: T](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, Try[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Try[U] = `try`.recoverWith[U](f)
    override def fail(error: Throwable): Try[T] = Failure(error)
}
```

But i wouldn't use `M[_]` definition here, as it's mostly used when you can actually concretise your `M[_]` inside your method, like:

```
trait Monad[M[_]] extends Applicative[M] {
  def flatMap[T, U](m: M[T])(fn: (T) => M[U]): M[U]
  ...
}
```

See Twitter's [Monad](https://github.com/twitter/algebird/blob/develop/algebird-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/algebird/Monad.scala) for instance. Actually, using `M[_]` is more Haskell-style as there is no classess, so monad itself is passed as parameter to method. So maybe you shoudn't use it at all and specify `trait Recoverable[M[T]]` directly.

Or you can do it Haskell style:

```
trait Recoverable[M[_]] {
    def recoverW[T, U >: T](m: M[T])(f: PartialFunction[Throwable, M[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): M[U]
    def fail[T](m: M[T])(error: Throwable): M[T]
}   

implicit val tryRecoverable = new Recoverable[Try] {
    override def recoverW[T, U >: T](`try`: Try[T])( f: PartialFunction[Throwable, Try[U]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Try[U] = `try`.recoverWith[U](f)
    override def fail[T](`try`: Try[T])( error: Throwable): Try[T] = Failure(error)
 }
```

Then use it as:

```
 scala> implicitly[Recoverable[Try]].recoverW(Try{"aaaa"})({case x => Try{"bbb"}})
 res54: scala.util.Try[String] = Success(aaaa)
```

Or just require it inside your function/class using `Try[T]: Recoverable` syntax sugar:

```
 def recover[T, Try[T]: Recoverable](t: Try[T]) = recoverW(t) _
```